# Using object's id in change_form_object_tools.html template

Tags: django, django-admin, django-urls

I have two buttons that appointing to different paths. And i want to pass the object.id with parameter.

**my urls**

```html
urlpatterns = [
    path('', admin.site.urls, name ='home'),
    path('dpo/imprimir/aprovado/<int:id>/',Aprovado, name ='aprovado'),
    path('dpo/imprimir/reprovado/<int:id>/',Reprovado, name ='reprovado'),
    ]
```

**My views**

```html
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from .models import Projeto


def Aprovado(request, id):
        obj = Projeto.objects.get(id=id)
        context = {
                "object": obj
        }
        return render(request, "dpo/imprimir/aprovado.html", context)

def Reprovado(request, id):
        obj = Projeto.objects.get(id=id)
        context = {
                "object": obj
        }
        return render(request, "dpo/imprimir/reprovado.html", context)
```

** My template**

```html
{% load i18n admin_urls %}
{% block object-tools-items %}
<li>
    <a href="{% url 'aprovado' object.id  %}">{% trans "Aprovado" %}</a></a>
</li>
<li>

    <a href="{% url 'reprovado' object.id  %}">{% trans "Aprovado" %}</a>
</li>
{% endblock %}
```

i think i am doing this the wrong way

Comment: What does this have to do with no reverse match?

Comment: because when i open my object , i have a error `NoReverseMatch`, and if i remove the `href`  from the `a` tag it is working but is not pointing to nowhere.

Comment: You should include the stack trace in the question

Comment: Show the view that renders that template.

Comment: @Alasdair i am adding 2 buttons in django template, i am changing the template `change_form_object_tools.html` so i dont have view , my only view is from my app

Comment: It looks as if `object` isn't set in the template context. Looking at [this template](https://github.com/django/django/blob/b9cf764be62e77b4777b3a75ec256f6209a57671/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/change_form_object_tools.html), it looks as if using `original.pk` instead of `object.id` might work. If that doesn't work, I would add [`{% debug %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#debug) to the template to find out what's in the context.

Comment: Yeh! it is working with `original.pk` but if i want to add some parameter that is not the `id` how can i do it?

Comment: Then you need to override the view and add the variable to the template context. Depending on what the parameter is, other options might be context processors, template tags and middleware.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The object id string is also available in the template context as `object_id`.

This can be seen in the source for `ModelAdmin._changeform_view()` [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3.1/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1623https://github.com/django/django/blob/3.1/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L1623).

Answer (score 6):

In the `change_form_object_tools.html` template, you should be able to access the object using `original`.

```
{% load i18n admin_urls %}
{% block object-tools-items %}
<li>
    <a href="{% url 'aprovado' original.pk  %}">{% trans "Aprovado" %}</a></a>
</li>
<li>

    <a href="{% url 'reprovado' original.pk  %}">{% trans "Aprovado" %}</a>
</li>
{% endblock %}
```

In general, you can use the `{% debug %}` tag or django-debug-toolbar to check what variables are in the template context.

Comment: but if I want to add some parameter that is not the `id` how can I do it?

Comment: That’s a separate question to your original question, so I can’t help with that. See my comment above for some hints.

Comment: The `debug` tag is described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#debug), but `original` does not seem to be mentioned explicitly in the documentation, other than [this example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-vs-replacing-an-admin-template).